# Is there a limit to queries using Bigquery's library and api?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I want to know if there is any limit when making queries to my data already loaded in bigquery?

For example, if I want to extract bigquery information from a web application or from a "web service", what is my limit of selects, updates and deletes?

The documentation tells me this:

Concurrent rate limit for interactive queries under on-demand pricing: 50 concurrent queries. Queries that return cached results, or queries configured using the dryRun property, do not count against this limit.

Daily query size limit: unlimited by default, but you may specify limits using custom quotas.

But I can not understand if I have a limit on the number of consultations per day, and if so, what is my limit?

Comment: What do you mean by "consultations"?

Comment: I want to know if there is a query limit per day using bigquery?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Also from what I understand, and from what the documentation tells me, each query is not immediate ?.
I really do not know if bigquery is the solution I need to store my information, I do not know if you could advise me in this regard through a chat? . Sorry for the lousyness of my English, I'm from Mexico and I do not speak the language.

Comment: What do you mean that each query is not immediate? Queries may take anywhere from a second or two to (at most) six hours, depending on how complex they are.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit to the number of slots you can allocate for queries at **a particular time**.

Some nuggets:

- **Slot**: represents one unit of computational capacity.
- **Query**: Uses as many slots as required so the query runs optimally  (Currently: MAX 50 slots for On Demand Price) **[A]**
- **Project**: The slots used per project is based on the number of queries that run at the same time (Currently: MAX 2000 slots for On Demand Price)

**[A]** This is all under the hood without user intervention. BigQuery makes an assessment of the query to calculate the number of slots required.

So if you do the math, worst case, if all your queries use 50 slots, you will not find any side effect until you have more than 40 queries running concurrently. Even in those situations, the queries will just be in the queue for a while and will start running after some queries are done executing.

Slots become more worrisome when you are time sensitive to getting your data on time and they are run in an environment where:

- A lot of queries are running at the same time.
- Most of those queries that are running at the same time usually take a long time to execute on an empty load.

The best way to understand whether these limits will impact you or not is by monitoring the current activity within your project. Bigquery advises you to monitor your slots with Stackdriver.

**Update:** Bigquery addresses the problem of query prioritization in one of their blog posts - [Truth 5: BigQuery supports query prioritization](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/12/busting-12-myths-about-bigquery)